# DataLayer in ASP.NET for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

What kind of datalayer is Stack Overflow using?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Answer (score 0):

See this:
[Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

Comment: I'm wondering what are the downvotes all about...